# How can I defocus all inputs on a page easily?

Tags: google-chrome, html, plugins, navigation, vimium

I'm using a Chrome extension called [Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb) which allows me to navigate quickly through a page, it inserts letters as commands on all the parts of the page that I can iteract with when I press <kbd>f</kbd> on the keyboard, but it is only enabled if the element I selected isn't an input (because if I press it on input, obviously I type something).

In some cases I'm having a little difficulty with navigation:

- When I open a page and it starts with an `input` focused, then I need to press <kbd>tab</kbd> to go to the next element, then I can use the extension as normal.
- When I select an `input` or other entry element, and there are many other inputs after that, I need to tap <kbd>tab</kbd> many times to escape all of them.

Is there a way to remove focus from all inputs on the page at once, or automatically?

Comment: Have you tried pressing `Esc`?

Comment: @davidmneedham It worked, thanks! That defocus the element and focus on `window` or something like that? Do you know the behaviour after the defocus?

Comment: After the input is not focused, you can use `f` to navigate with links as if you navigated to a page without any inputs focused from the start.

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by @davidmneedham, pressing <kbd>esc</kbd> works.